# how to get information of child node .?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jstree in demo .i want to get information of child.I want to get id of children whenver user click there parent node.

here is my expected output

- 1) "a" element don't have child so if user click on it it array is null;
- 2) "b" element have two child "b-a","b-b" .so if user click on it it array id of these two element;
- 3) "b-a" element don't have child so if user click on it it array is null;
- 4) "b-b" element have two child "b-b-a","b-b-b" .so if user click on it it array id of these two element;
  fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/8/

  $(document).ready(function () {

  ```
  $('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
      alert("node_id: " + data.node.id);
      $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(data.node);

      var selEl = [];
      $(this).siblings().each(function (idx, el) {
          selEl.push($(el.node).attr("id"));
      });
      console.log(selEl);
  });
  $('#tree').jstree({
      "core": {
          "check_callback": true
      },
      "plugins": ["dnd"]
  });
  $('#home').click(function () {
      alert('home');

  });
  $('#next').click(function () {
      alert('next');

  });
  $('#pre').click(function () {
      alert('pre');

  });
  ```

  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Get children id:

```
$(data.node.children).each(function(index, item){
    console.log(item);  // <-- logs the item id to console
});
```

Get root nodes when home is pushed:

```
$('#home').click(function () {
    var rootChildren = $('#tree').find('ul > li');
    $(rootChildren).each(function(index, item){
        console.log(item.id); // <-- logs root node id to console
    });
    //alert('home');
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/11/)

**Original Answer**

Use

```
data.node.children
```

ex.

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var nodeChildren = data.node.children;  // <- get children
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Updated your fiddle to alert children instead of id -
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/9/)

Comment: how to get id of that children ?

Comment: is it possible to get all first level node when user click home button .It mean if user click home button it show "a" and "b"

Comment: you are showing id's not text ?console.log(item.id); // can we show text ? answer is same beacuse id and text is same

Comment: secondly when user press any element example "a" and "b" it become highlight "using " active class. can we move active class using next and previous button

Comment: one more issue it  is giving id only not text data.node.children .http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/13/